# error on Magento 2 Integration Test

Tags: integration-test

when trying to execute dev:test:run integration getting following error

```
Next Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException: Command returned non-zero exit code:
`mysqldump --defaults-extra-file='/var/www/magento206/dev/tests/integration/tmp/sandbox-0-ca4ee7e931dcd5242e686eaa1575d816/defaults_extra.cnf' --host='127.0.0.1'  'magento_integration_tests' > '/var/www/magento206/dev/tests/integration/tmp/sandbox-0-ca4ee7e931dcd5242e686eaa1575d816/setup_dump_magento_integration_tests.sql' 2>&1` in /var/www/magento206/vendor/magento/framework/Shell.php:62
```

Through PHPStorm getting this

```
Exception: Starting Magento uninstallation:
[Zend_Db_Statement_Exception]
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'magento.core_config_data' doesn't exist, query was: SELECT `main_table`.`config_id`, `main_table`.`path`, `main_table`.`value` FROM `core_config_data` AS `main_table` WHERE (`scope` = 'default')
[PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'magento.core_config_data' doesn't exist
setup:uninstall [--magento-init-params="..."]

Next Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException: Command returned non-zero exit code:
`mysqldump --defaults-extra-file='/var/www/magento206/dev/tests/integration/tmp/sandbox-0-ca4ee7e931dcd5242e686eaa1575d816/defaults_extra.cnf' --host='127.0.0.1'  'magento_integration_tests' > '/var/www/magento206/dev/tests/integration/tmp/sandbox-0-ca4ee7e931dcd5242e686eaa1575d816/setup_dump_magento_integration_tests.sql' 2>&1` in /var/www/magento206/vendor/magento/framework/Shell.php:62
```

- dev/tests/integration/phpunit.xml - is properly pointed
- dev/tests/integration/etc/install-config-mysql.php - correctly
  configured.

Comment: I also have the same problem for Magento 2.1.1 using Cpanel

Comment: So it seems like the mysql import is failing

Comment: Did you fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I had the first error the author mentioned and it turned out that I did not have `mysqldump` installed.

Answer (score -2):

You need to config all the php files under this path

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\ ..\dev\tests\integration\etc
```